# Confusion when using String Resources

Tags: android, android-resources

There is one confusion in my mind, that why we are using **String Resources?** Instead of **Hardcoded Text?** To write a text in Android

Comment: Imagine you want to change your strings at any time, without having to search through tens of thousands of lines in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is to be able to traduce your app to other languages.

You can have different value folders (each with their strings.xml file) for different languages so you don't have to modify a single line of your code.

Here you can find how: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Answer (score 0):

Primarily 2 reasons:

- Multilingual support.
- Same reason why we use constants in code - to
  reduce duplication